# Uncaught TYPO3 Exception when managing packages with composer

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-10.x

I have a TYPO3 10.4 instance with several extensions installed (composer mode) where there a re several extensions running, one of those extensions is vicrepmad/v_stat.
When I installed that Extension there was no problem whatsoever. But once it is installed, it is impossible to remove any other extension with composer since I always get following error:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception #1519931815: The package "v_stat" depends on "typo3/cms-fluid" which is not present in the system.
thrown in file /app/WWW/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Package/PackageManager.php
in line 1110
```

The composer.json looks like this:

```
    {
    "name": "vicrepmad/v-stat",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "type": "typo3-cms-extension",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.x.x-dev",
        },
        "typo3/cms": {
            "web-dir": ".Build/Typo3/Web",
            "extension-key": "v_stat"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "typo3/cms-core": "^10.0",
        "typo3/cms-backend": "^10.0",
        "typo3/cms-frontend": "^10.0",
        "typo3/cms-extbase": "^10.0",
        "typo3/cms-fluid": "^10.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "typo3/testing-framework": "^6.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.14",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12",
        "saschaegerer/phpstan-typo3": "^0.12.0",
        "phpstan/extension-installer": "^1.0",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "5.1.0",
        "phpunit/phpcov": "^8.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "VICREPMAD\\VStat\\": "Classes"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": ".Build/Typo3/vendor/",
        "bin-dir": ".Build/Typo3/bin/"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "link-extension": [
            "@php -r 'is_dir($extFolder=__DIR__.\"/.Build/Typo3/Web/typo3conf/ext/\") || mkdir($extFolder, 0777, true);'",
            "@php -r 'file_exists($extFolder=__DIR__.\"/.Build/Typo3/Web/typo3conf/ext/v_stat\") || symlink(__DIR__,$extFolder);'"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@link-extension"
        ]
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong with the extension?

Comment: I had exactly that error in v11.1.1 while trying to activate/deactivate extensions with Extension Manager. I noticed I don't have it any more with current master. Maybe it was fixed for you in current 10.4.x-dev as well? Sorry, haven't investigated any further....

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same with TYPO3 v10.4.21. Did you solve the problem?